# Make Xcode editor transparent?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I am used to using iTerm for most of my programming work, but with iOS, Xcode really is the superior tool. However, I have grown very accustomed to working with a transparent terminal. Is there anyway I could make Xcode's editor transparent?

I tried messing around with the opacity in preferences but that doesn't seem to do what I want. Ideally, I would like to be able to look at the application behind my Xcode code. Is this possible?

Comment: I doubt that it's possible.  Xcode is one of the most opaque IDEs I've ever encountered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although XCode doesn't have this functionality built in, you can achieve the same effect by installing Afloat from Infinite Labs: http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/

Then, once it's installed, you can make XCode transparent:

[image: Transparent XCode]

Answer (score 0):

### No.

There is no built-in option to do this within Xcode. There may be some utilities to make a window translucent, but I highly doubt it.

I like a terminal that looks like a sheet of Mylar. I don't like my editor to look like a sheet of Mylar. That's just personal preference, but still...